# On base locus of canoncal linear system on surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $S$ be a minimal surface of general type over $\mathbb{C}$ with $p_g=h^0(K_S)>1$. As a convention, we can write $|K_S|=|M|+F$ such that $F$ is the fixed part. We know that $K_SM \le K_S^2$.

However, is there a lower bound of $K_SM$ given by $K_S^2$? For example, $K_SM \ge aK_S^2$, which means that $K_SF$ can not be too big.

Comment: Well, if $M^2>0$, the Hodge index theorem gives 
$$
K^2\le \frac{(K.M)^2}{M^2}\le (K.M)^2
$$

Comment: Yes, right. But as $p_g$ goes large, this bound seems not so beautiful. I do not know if there is a linear bound.

Comment: If the canonical image of $S$ is a surface, then $M^2\ge p_g-1$. This improves the bound suggested by JC.

Comment: @rita: right. But I think using the technique of the proof of Noether inequality, maybe $M^2 \ge 2p_g-4$.

Comment: @Michael: that's right.